# How do I change the width of a separator line in the footer?

Tags: alignment, footer, center, separator

I'm using the **Ocean WP** theme and I want to align the footer content in center.  The content consist of my logo, a separator line and Privacy Policy and Terms of Service links. The content aligns on left side and will not align center and the separator line is full width instead of a short line. This function works fine on my other sites. Please help...

React

Reply

I'm using the Ocean Wp theme. I tried to align center in Footer Widgets and Widgets. I'm using one center column but content is aligning on left side with a long separator line instead of a short one.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Stack overflow is a coding forum where you suppose to get help with specific coding issues. Questions about how to use a commercial Wordpress theme should go to their support. But maybe you are lucky and someone using the same theme can help you here ..